# split string if next chracter is specific character e.g 'abc'

Tags: php, regex

I currently have a string shown below,

```
$string = "4WL533cba00780352524MT_FAILED(SCRNotInAllowList)                  STATUS_NOT_AVAILABLE";
```

I followed online tutorial shows:

```
(gif|jpg)   Matches either "gif" or "jpeg".
```

From my case i only need to split when the text contain DN_ or MT_

```
$data = preg_split("/[\s,(DN_|MT_),]+/", trim($string));
```

output

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4WL533cba00780352524
        [1] => FAILE
        [2] => SCR
        [3] => otInAllowList
        [4] => S
        [5] => A
        [6] => US
        [7] => O
        [8] => AVAILABLE
    )
```

however I expect the output to be:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4WL533cba00780352524
        [1] => MT_FAILED(SCRNotInAllowList)
        [2] => STATUS_NOT_AVAILABLE
    )
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your regex pattern you wrap the intended pattern in a character class and fail to use the alternation operator - you might wish to have a look at [this regex site](http://regular-expression.info) for detailed explanations of basic syntax of regular expressions, the background theory and extension features in common regex engines.

In your code use

```
$data = preg_split("/\s+|(?=DN_|MT_)/", trim($string));
```

Brief explanation of the pattern:

you want to split either at sequences of whitespace or on occurrences of one of the strings 'DN_', 'MT_'.   In the latter case you want the match of the split pattern be a part of the next element in the result array. Therefore you enclose the pattern in the positive lookahead operator which provides trailing context for a match. Effectively this matches the empty string if this match is followed by 'DN_' or 'MT_'.

Comment: Wonder how did you come to this solution.

Comment: Oh, I see now; you did copy/paste from my answer. :)

Comment: @mpapec independently of you, contrary to what you appear to insinuate, though matching (no pun intended) the OP's spec at the second attempt only. otherwise i feel our answers to be sufficiently different to coexist (specifically you do not annotate the raw solution).

Comment: @mpapec just noticed your second remark which is unjustified and impertinent. Please note that the intricacies of regex engines are public knowledge which many people know how to access, to understand, and to apply without your guidance. For any further discussion of the controversy I suggest to move to the chat.

Comment: Well yes, you've added explanation to my answer, that is correct. Let me just remind you what was your [first attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/a7da435f-e99c-47f4-bbe4-8f2e71601c66/view-source) before you copy/pasted solution without referencing to original.

Comment: @mpapec your claim doesn't gain veracity by repetition. as you can read in my first comment, my first solution was indeed incorrect as i first didn't get that the OP wanted the dn_/mt_ strings in his results.

Comment: And I'm afraid you're disputed by this thread chronology and answer history.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52367/discussion-between-collapsar-and-mpapec)

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = "4WL533cba00780352524MT_FAILED(SCRNotInAllowList)                  STATUS_NOT_AVAILABLE";

$data = preg_split("/\s+|(?=DN_|MT_)/", trim($string));
print_r($data);
```

output

```
Array
(
[0] => 4WL533cba00780352524
[1] => MT_FAILED(SCRNotInAllowList)
[2] => STATUS_NOT_AVAILABLE
)
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out. I hope most of the programmer out there encounter the same issue as i did.